# Combining four tables into two tables, with linked unique column ids

Tags: mysql

I have two databases, both with two tables, and want to move one set of the tables into the other set through some method. The problem I am having is the tables have linked ids, and the ids should be unique, but duplicates are found upon migration. By linked id's, I mean that the id found in account_info_{1|2} are connected to the account_id found in notes_{1|2}. The first method I thought of is a simple sql script such as `

```
INSERT INTO 
db_1.account_info_1
SELECT null, username FROM db_2.account_info_2;

INSERT INTO db_1.notes_1
SELECT null, note FROM db_2.notes_2;`
```

This script works in the sense that now there will no longer be any more duplicate id's, as it allows sql to auto-increment the id's from db_2 accordingly. The problem with this is now the id's from db_2.account_info_2 are no longer linked with the account_id's from db_2.notes_2. Is there are the way to migrate the data from db_2 to db_1, while avoiding unlinking the id's and preventing duplicates?

Note: I am sure I could develop a php script of some sort to solve this problem, but I am moreover looking for an sql script, as a php script is going to be lenghty in comparison to the sql script (I assume)

**account_info_1**

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | usernameOfId1 |
| 2 | usernameOfId2 |

**notes_1**

| id | account_id | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1stNoteOfId1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2ndNoteOfId1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1stNoteOfId2 |

**account_info_2**

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AcctTwoUsername |
| 2 | AnotherAcctTwoUsername |

**notes_2**

| id | account_id | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1stNoteOfId1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2ndNoteOfId1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1stNoteOfId2 |

Answer (score 1):

You make3 it to complicate.

As you can see MySQL doesn' Matter if you insert the ids to when you rin your ÌNSERT INTO ..SELECT`

he also can "knows" which the next number is, so copy all data from One data base to the second.

I don't  know, why you need this, but have you thought about replication, so that changes get automatically copied

> ```
> CREATE TABLE account_info_1
>     (`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `username` varchar(13))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO account_info_1
>     (`id`, `username`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'usernameOfId1'),
>     (2, 'usernameOfId2'),
>     (5, 'usernameOfId2')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE account_info_2
>     (`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `username` varchar(13))
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO account_info_2 SELECT * FROM account_info_1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM account_info_2
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username     
> -: | :------------
>  1 | usernameOfId1
>  2 | usernameOfId2
>  5 | usernameOfId2
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO account_info_2 values (NULL,'test')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM account_info_2
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username     
> -: | :------------
>  1 | usernameOfId1
>  2 | usernameOfId2
>  5 | usernameOfId2
>  6 | test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf11dc376269316d066b926f95ee7635)*